# How do you access the name of the image in a picturebox in Visual Studio using C#

Tags: c#, picturebox

I have a program which has 16 grid tiles using picturebox but only uses 5 images, the rest of the tiles are just a black image.

I would like to be able to tell which image the 'user' clicks on.

I have a method called image_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

I have an if statement inside this method that states:

```
if (peckedSquare.BackColor == Color.Black)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Pecked a black square");
    return;
}
```

This sends a String that lets me know when a black square has been clicked.

Is there an easy way to perhaps say:

//pseudo code:

```
if (peckedSquare.ImageName == pigeon1.png)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Pecked Pigeon number 1");
}
```

I have googled my query but I have not found any suitable answers.

//EDIT
I have just re-read my code.
I was assigning each picture to a picturebox square using a randomnumber.
I had this random number as a variable, so I can just use that variable to determine which image was clicked.
ie.

```
if (randomNumber == 1)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Pecked Pigeon number 1");
}
```

or better than that

```
pigeonSelected = randomNumber + 1 //as I am using an array to store the images
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Pecked Pigeon Number {0}", pigeonSelected);
```

Comment: You can't do that.  An image exists in memory and doesn't keep track of what it came from.

Comment: `PictureBox.ImageLocation` Property? If `PictureBox.Load` was used: "A call to the Load method will overwrite the ImageLocation property, setting ImageLocation to the URL value specified in the method call."

Comment: I'm assuming your just using windows forms PictureBox here. Could you save references to the image(s) and then compare the "((PictureBox)sender).Image" property to the list of images you have stashed?

Comment: @drew_w I am using a List array of images and randomly picking an image from that list. So I could just say if ((PictureBox)sender).Image == pigeonPics[0] then pigeon1.png was clicked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As quick & dirty solution I would use `Tag` property for that, `null` for black tiles and file path for the others (and it's always available, even if your image comes from resources), something like this:

```
if (peckedSquare.Tag == null)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Pecked a black square");
}
else
{
    switch (Path.GetFileName(peckedSquare.Tag.ToString()))
    {
        case "pigeon1.png":
        break;
    }
}
```

Of course when you create tiles you have to store file path in `Tag`:

```
PictureBox tile = new PictureBox();
tile.Image = Image.FromFile(path); // Or another source, of course
tile.Tag = path;
```

As alternative you may even use `Name` property for this, each control is named (primary for designer-code integration) but if you create controls at run-time you can set that value to anything you want (not only valid identifiers). Same usage as above just no need to call `ToString()`.

**How to Improve?**

Please let me say this solution is not very OOP. Even without a big refactoring we can do little bit better. Note that you can store whatever you want in `Tag` property. A number, a simple string unrelated to file name or even (maybe better) a `class` or an `enum` that represents that image (to delegate action to that object). This is a very raw example:

```
abstract class Tile {
    public abstract void Activate();
}

sealed class EmptyTile : Tile {
    public virtual void Activate() {
        Debug.WriteLine("Pecked a black square");
    }
}

sealed class ImageTile : Tile {
    public ImageTile(string content) {
        _content = content;
    }

    public virtual void Activate() {
        Debug.WriteLine(_content);
    }

    private string _content;
}
```

In this way in your click event handler you can do this:

```
((Tile)peckedTile.Tag).Activate();
```

No need to check what's inside or to compare with `null`. No `if` and no `switch`, just don't forget to put proper object (`ImageTile` or `BlackTile`) when you create tiles.

Comment: I think this answer best suits my current code. I will use this and see if it helps.

Comment: @pythonReuser give a chance to second example too. It's much more readable and little bit more _object oriented_ (just a little bit).

Answer (score 0):

Use [`PictureBox.Load(string)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/f6ak7was%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method to load images from file. Then the file path will be stored in the 
[`PictureBox.ImageLocation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/system.windows.forms.picturebox.imagelocation%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property:

> A call to the Load method will overwrite the ImageLocation property, setting ImageLocation to the URL value specified in the method call.

So you can write for example:

```
if (peckedSquare.ImageLocation.EndsWith("pigeon1.png"))
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Pecked Pigeon number 1");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this using the Tag property like @Adriano suggested:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    pictureBox1.Click += pictureBox_Click;
    pictureBox2.Click += pictureBox_Click;
    pictureBox3.Click += pictureBox_Click;
    // ...
    pictureBox1.Tag = "picture1.png";
    pictureBox2.Tag = "picture2.png";
    pictureBox3.Tag = "picture3.png";
}

void pictureBox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PictureBox pb = sender as PictureBox;

    if (pb.BackColor != Color.Black)
        Debug.WriteLine(pb.Tag.ToString());
    else
        Debug.WriteLine("Black image");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you could do something like the following:

```
    private List<PictureBox> pictures = null;
    string[] ImageNames = new string[]
            {
                "images\\test_1.jpg",
                "images\\test_2.jpg"
            };

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        pictures = new List<PictureBox>();
        for (var idx = 0; idx < ImageNames.Length; idx++)
        {
            pictures.Add(new PictureBox());
            pictures[idx].Image = new Bitmap(ImageNames[idx]);
            pictures[idx].Click += OnClick;

            // you'll want to set the offset and everything so it shows at the right place
            Controls.Add(pictures[idx]);
        }
    }

    private void OnClick(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        // you'll definitely want error handling here
        var ImageName = ImageNames[pictures.IndexOf((PictureBox) sender)];
    }
```

You can see that in the click method you will be able to get the image name, which is what you are looking for I believe.

As others have said, you can also use the "Tag" property assuming you weren't already using this for some other purpose. The nice thing about tag is you can probably also edit it through the form designer which allows you to lay things out a little more nicely than the automatic layout I used above. Good luck!