# assigning 'parent' attribute to a changing object (name stored in control array)

Tags: c#, arrays, controls, parent

I have 6 images which need to use transparency. They can be toggled on and off. I need to set it so that if a picture (which is a parent) is toggled off then the picture above will be assigned to the next available parent.

To do this I store the 'next available parent' image name in a control array, and set the 'former child' image's parent to this control array

(There are two control arrays as both the parent and the child can change depending on what button is pressed)

This is the line of code i am trying to get working~:

```
updatedParentFaction[0].parent = parentFaction[0];
```

If the child who's parent is being changed wasn't different every time i would just write

```
imageB.parent = parentFaction[0];   //for example
```

Is there a way to make it accept whats stored in the 'updatedParentFaction' array as the name of the child I wish to change?

**UPDATE**

Ok so I am going to provide further information here:

There are six picture boxes called 'image A','image B' etc all the way up to 'image F'.

They are all the same size and in the same location (one on top of the other - using transparency to show them on top of each other).

When the program runs they are all 'Hidden' and by pressing the corresponding button they can be made visible (if you press 'show imageA' then image A is visible - pressing the button again renders the image hidden)

The parent image will always be the first alphabetical image which is turned on, every image after this will be a subsequent child of that parent but in order.

example:
If image A + Image B + Image D are are visible and C,E + F are hidden. Then the main parent image will be A (Image B will be a child of A and image D will be a child of image B)

Using this method the first time the program is run and the images are switched on the Transparency works.
However, (using the above example) if i was to make image B hidden then image D would be hidden also.

I am trying to write my code so that when a parent image is turned off, the child will change its parent to the next available parent; in the above example if Image B was turned off, then Image D would change its parent to Image A.

Using the line of code:

```
updatedParentFaction[0].parent = parentFaction[0];
```

The Name of 'Child' image that needs its parent changing is stored in 'updatedParentFaction[0]' and the parent faction that i need to assign is stored in 'parentFaction[0]'

So using the above Example, Image A,B + D are turned on. Image B = Child of Image A, Image D = child of Image B.

Image B is then turned off, Image D now needs to be a child of Image A.

I tried using the piece of code i just explained but the code reads 'set the parent of this array to parentFaction[0]'

I need the code to read 'set the control with the name stored in updatedParentFaction[0] as a child of the name stored in parentFaction[0]

Hope this helps, if not ill display my code but I thought explaining it might just be easier.

Comment: I think it'll be more clear if you post a small code example of what you want to do. For example...what imageB is?

Comment: What I don't understand now is...why do you have to change parents? They're overlapped and transparent...

Comment: If all the images are turned on then B is a child of A, C is a child of B etc, the problem is when i set Image B to hidden then the only images which are displayed are Image A -(Image C is a child of B so its hidden as well, Image D is a child of C and because C is hidden D is also hidden and so on and so forth)

Comment: Then, given an image C you want to find its first visible ancestor? (=A or B, first one is visible in reverse search order)

Comment: If A,B + D are turned on, then i click the 'turn Image B Off' button two if statements run. The first runs forward (alphabetically) to find out the 'next' image which is turned on - identify the child which needs changing - (In this case Image D) The name is then stored in updateParentFaction[0] array. The second if statement runs backwards to figure out the name of the parent (in this case Image A) and stores it in the parentFaction[0] array. Now that i have both names i need to write the code: imageD.parent = imageA (But, i need to set it so it takes the names stored in the array instead)

Comment: The main problem is that i dont know how to write: imageA.parent ----- when i wrote updateParentFaction[0].parent ---- i get an error saying you can't assign a parent to an array.

Comment: No, I'm not talking about what you're trying to do but what you have to achieve. I don't see why you have to keep parentFaction array if all data you need is in controls array itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give a `PictureBox` array pictures you may use these functions to change visibility.

This one will set visibility for item with given index and all its children:

```
void SetVisible(PictureBox[] pictures, int index, bool visible) {
    for (int i=index; i < pictures.Length; ++i)
        pictures[i].Visible = visible;
}
```

Same as above but using object reference instead of index:

```
void SetVisible(PictureBox[] pictures, PictureBox item, bool visible) {
    SetVisible(pictures, Array.IndexOf(item), visible);
}
```

To find first visible ancestor of item with a given index:

```
int FindFirstVisibleAncestorIndex(PictureBox[] pictures, int index) {
    for (int i=index; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (pictures[i].Visible)
            return i;
    }

    return -1;
}
```

The other overloads are pretty straightforward.

Comment: This method seems much more efficient then my current script, will require further research on my part to apply successfully but I think this is a great answer, Thanks!

Comment: @user3178614 you welcome, I'm sorry without more context I can't provide a more specific solution!

Comment: Thanks again for the help, but I am stuck trying to figure out how now to set the parent of an image stored in the array, is it something along the lines of: pictures[3].parent = pictures[2];

Comment: @user3178614 can you show _some_ more code? What's declaration of pictures? If it's an array of PictureBox you can use Tag property (like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21031319/how-do-you-access-the-name-of-the-image-in-a-picturebox-in-visual-studio-using-c/21031426#21031426)). If it's just a plain Image object then you don't have such _feature_. What I'm trying to say is that actually you may not need to store image's parent. If this attribute comes from visibility you can always (re)compute it when needed. Instead, if you're trying to manage a complex object graph you may...

Comment: ...simply wrap your Image object (whatever it is) within a custom class with all the properties you need. But again a working example of what you're trying to do will help us a lot to understand your code. From description we can't infer types...