# Detecting which image is used in an imagebox

Tags: c#, image, picturebox

I'm trying too make a memory game.
In this game when a button is klicked the button and an picturebox will be send into a List.
I want too use the images inside the pictureboxes as a way too use this code. But even when the two images are the same the code wont work. Is there a way too check the image used like `Name.jpg`.

```
if(buttonCount == 2)
{
    if(pictureList[0].Image == pictureList[1].Image)
    {
        buttonCount = 0;
        buttonList.RemoveAt(0)
        buttonList.RemoveAt(0);
        pictureList.RemoveAt(0);
        pictureList.RemoveAt(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21031319/how-do-you-access-the-name-of-the-image-in-a-picturebox-in-visual-studio-using-c/21031528#21031528

Comment: Just as a little side note: Do NOT call your game "Memory" - this name is protected and you could get sued - did already happen to someone...

Answer (score 1):

You could save an Id of the image (or e.g. the filename like you suggested) in the `Tag`.
So when loading the image into the picture box:

```
string path = "PATH";
pictureBox.Image = Image.FromFile(path);
pictureBox.Tag = path;
```

Then you could compare the Tag.

BUT I think (show us how you load the images please) this is not working as it is, because you load the image twice from the disk like:

```
pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(path);
pictureBox2.Image = Image.FromFile(path);
```

Because then you have differen instances and so the equals returns false.
If you do it like the following it should also work:

```
var image = Image.FromFile(path);
pictureBox1.Image = image;
pictureBox2.Image = image;
```

Answer (score 0):

In your current application, you do not have enough information associated with the image object to identify it.  As such, you need to possibly extend the `Image` class to include this information or store it in some other way for comparison.

Extending `Image` class

```
public class GameImage : Image
{
    public static GameImage GetImage(string filename)
    {
        GameImage img = (GameImage)Image.FromFile(filename);
        img.FileName = filename;
        return img;
    }

    public string FileName { get; private set; }
}
```

Then the comparison becomes

```
if(buttonCount == 2)
{
    if(((GameImage)pictureList[0].Image).FileName == ((GameImage)pictureList[1].Image).FileName)
    {
        buttonCount = 0;
        buttonList.RemoveAt(0)
        buttonList.RemoveAt(0);
        pictureList.RemoveAt(0);
        pictureList.RemoveAt(0);
    }
}
```

Note: Note tested!

Comment: `(GameImage)Image.FromFile(filename)` will not work, as you can not cast a base class to it's derived class (only the other way around).