# Getting resources Image path from Picturebox

Tags: c#, picturebox

I have six pictureboxes and images with names 1 to 6. When form load, randomly six images appeared in pictureboxes. I click on any picturebox it should show me the image name, but it shows only the last randomly generated image name when I click any picturebox. I tried this [How do you access the name of the image in a picturebox in Visual Studio using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21031319/how-do-you-access-the-name-of-the-image-in-a-picturebox-in-visual-studio-using-c), but not get my job done. I don't want to use *tag property*.

```
     {
   ........
   for (i = 0; i < box.Count; i++)
        {
            int rand = r.Next(1, 7);
            int randM1 = rand - 1;

            imgname = name[randM1];
            box[i].Image = (Bitmap)rm.GetObject(imgname);
            box[i].Click += new EventHandler(Pop_Up);
        }

        }

    private void Pop_Up(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var pb = sender as PictureBox;
        if (pb != null)
            MessageBox.Show(imgname);
    }
```

Comment: If you don't store it, maybe in the Tag when loading it you won't get it afterwards form the Image alone, I'm afraid.

Comment: @TaW well see my edit.

Comment: _I don't want to use tag property._ Well, then you are free to invent something else. - You can use the debugger to drill into the picturebox and its image as I have done. If you find what you need good! come back and tell us. But I doubt it is there; I found nothing..

Comment: @TaW Problem is I am getting only last image name generated by random number. I need that when I click any image I should get its name.

Comment: As I said: You need it? You make it! Why can't you store the names?? And why don't you want to use the Tag? You can always use a `Dictionary<PictureBox, string>` to store the names when you set the images..